# Transfer Songbird metadata to new computer

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, metadata, songbird

I recently decided to move from my ancient Windows 7 (32bit) laptop to a newer Windows 7 64bit one. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble transferring my Songbird library.

I copied the folder with all my music files, and it imported just fine on the new computer. However all the metadata such as play counts and playlists is missing. Does anyone know how I can transfer it? I've tried searching online, but I wasn't able to find anything that looks helpful.

As I understand it, Songbird stores this information in an internal database somewhere, but I was unable to find the database, and I don't know if copying it over would even work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few places where programs commonly store their additional data. Songbird's directory containing its settings and some other files should be in one of these - you just have to copy it over to the same place on your new PC.

- *%appdata%* - actually an alias to *Application Data\Roaming* directory. Type `%appdata%` in the Start menu search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it.
- *Application Data\Local* - go one level up from *%appdata%* and you'll find a directory called *Local*, that's it.
- *Program Data* - it's located in your system drive's root and can be hidden, type `C:\Program Data` in the Start menu search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it. This is a less common one, used for system-wide, user-independent data.
- Application's directory - the folder where an app is installed, usually located in *C:\Program Files* (or *C:\Program Files (x86)* if it's a 32-bit program installed in a 64-bit OS). Sometimes overwriting this directory with the old one also copies all settings and data.

In the latter case remember that you'll have to move that folder to appropriate directory - Songbird is a 32-bit app, so it will probably be installed in *Program Files (x86)* on the new PC, but in *Program Files* on the old one.

Comment: I copied my appdata Local/Songbird2 and Roaming/Songbird2 over the folders on my new computer and everything worked. Thanks!