# Transfer real player playlists from one installation to another

Tags: windows-7, realplayer

I just did a clean install of Windows, and I'm looking to recover my Real Player playlists. I saved all the files from my old installation, so I'm hoping I can just move some files from my old installation to the program files for my new installation. Does anyone have any idea which files I need to move? Or if this is even possible?

Comment: have a look at [Transfer Songbird metadata to new computer](http://superuser.com/q/591811) which mentions few common locations

Comment: Wow, RealPlayer. I'm surprised someone still uses that malware in this day and age.

Comment: I know I know. It's terrible. I've just invested so many hours organizing tracks by artist into chronological order. As far as I know there isn't a program that will do this for you right?

Comment: @n_i_c_k: Not sure I follow what you did exactly. Do the files (which format?) have the relevant metadata tags such as artist, year etc. set? BTW, don't forget to use @ name (without a space) to ping someone if you've left a comment.